# How to manipulate the status of current job-execution from inside of an inline script?

Tags: rundeck

The following code returns an error to rundeck.

```
#!/bin/bash
exit -1
```

And rundeck decides how to deal with it by running the next step or changing the execution "status" to "failed".

I would like to modify the status directly by inline script to support more than 2 states. I need "succeeded", "failed" and "nodata" to express that the data are missing.

Is there a way to express this?

Answer (score 1):

There is none. Just like bash can return zero or non-zero

One possible alternative is raise an exception with message `nodata` and exit with non-zero code. Rundeck will mark this job as fail with NonZeroResultCode error. You should be able to get your error message `nodata` with `${result.message}`